# How to add values in existing array dynamically in senchatouch2

Tags: arrays, sencha-touch-2, push, addition, dynamically-generated

Using push() method i added values in array,but when i add again using push() values are added in separate array..How to add values in existing array dynamically?kindly provide help with sample piece of code

Comment: If i add values statically inside Array using push() its working fine,But if i add values dynamically its not working

Comment: show some code please

Comment: I solved the issue..I made mistake in Array declaration..When i declared it globally i can add values in existing array

Comment: How is this sencha-touch question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare array globally like

> var arr = [];

then add values inside array using push() method like,

> arr.push(Ext.getCmp('id').getValue());

like this we can add values in existing array dynamically..